# SPARQL: Federated query gives no result when using local file, while same query on dbpedia does

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, stardog, federated-queries

the local file uploaded on stardog:

```
@prefix dbo:    <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> .
@prefix dbr:    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> .
dbr:United_States   dbo:leader  dbr:John_Roberts ,
    dbr:Joe_Biden ,
    dbr:Barack_Obama ,
    dbr:Paul_Ryan .
```

1.query using the local file:

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?person ?o
FROM <http://example.com/leaders.ttl>
WHERE{

  dbr:United_States dbo:leader ?person .
  SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {  ?person dbo:abstract ?o .}

}
```

2.Same query using only dbpedia will give results:

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?person ?o
FROM <http://example.com/leaders.ttl>
WHERE{

  #dbr:United_States dbo:leader ?person .
  SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> { dbr:United_States dbo:leader ?person.  ?person dbo:abstract ?o.}

}
```

Using the second query will result in a colum with the leaders and a column of abstract of the leaders in all languages available from dbpedia. Why does the first query where I use the local rdf file not work? The select query on the local file with `dbr:United_States dbo:leader ?person .` returns exactly the same column with the same leaders as running it directly on the dbpedia endpoint: `dbpedia:John_Roberts, dbpedia:Joe_Biden, dbpedia:Barack_Obama, dbpedia:Paul_Ryan`.

Why does the first query give no results?

Comment: And the file was loaded into the correct graph `http://example.com/leaders.ttl`?

Comment: @Jerry, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862589/sparql-federated-query-not-returning-all-solutions#comment80674780_46862589